# Dependent and independent variable in PLS regression for sensor array data

Tags: pattern-recognition, partial-least-squares, sensor-data

I have been using PCA for the pattern recognition of my gas sensor array data. But recently decided to use PLS using OriginPro software. My sensor array data consists of responses coming from 8-10 sensors (used as columns) which I use as variable data. My target is to quantify the analytes which in my case is for 4-5 different concentrations for 2-3 analytes (38 rows of data). I have 4 replicates for each of the concentrations of each analyte. I am trying to use 1 replicate as testing data and the other three replicates as training data for the regression. The OriginPro software asks for independent and dependent variables in my data. Sensor responses vary depending on the analyte and its concentration. My question is how should I organize the data for the PLS analysis?  Should I use concentrations as the independent variable and sensor responses as the dependent variable? If so, I have a few concentrations that match for different analytes.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you to the awesome people in this group.

Cheers,
Ali